# Zero-downtime indexing with Hibernate-Search

Tags: hibernate-search

Trying to implement the logic for `Zero-downtime` reindexing as advised on: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-indexlayout-strategy-simple.
Dependency details:

1. springBootVersion=3.1.1
2. hibernateVersion=6.1.7.Final
3. hibernate_search=6.2.0.Beta1
4. backend: Elastic Search

Below is the pseudo code that we have implemented. Everything executes functionally.

However need some suggestions in implementing on how to initiate `MassIndexer` (method `processIndex`). The approach we have opted is executing `MassIndexer` one per each entity.

Tried to use  massindexer as a class level variable field but it fails the application start.

Thanks in advance!!

Here is the pseudo code for `MassIndexServiceImpl.java`:

```
import MassIndexService;

import org.apache.commons.****;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;

import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;

import org.hibernate.search.backend.elasticsearch.***;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.***;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.massindexing.***;

import org.slf4j.*;
import org.springframework.****;

import java.*****;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.IndexState;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;

@Service
@Transactional
public class MassIndexServiceImpl implements MassIndexService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MassIndexServiceImpl.class);

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private final MassIndexingMonitor monitor;

    private final ElasticsearchClient client;

    private final SearchSession searchSession;

    public MassIndexServiceImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;

        // Create the low-level client
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // And create the API client
        client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        monitor = new PojoMassIndexingLoggingMonitor(1000);

        searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
    }

    /**
     * Zero-Downtime Implementation Method for MassIndexing All Entities in the running instance
     *
     * @param
     * @return void.
     */
    @Async
    @Override
    public void reindexAliases() {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    SearchMapping mapping = Search.mapping(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
    AtomicInteger successful = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger failures = new AtomicInteger();
    mapping
        .allIndexedEntities()
        .stream()
        .forEach(entity -> {
            processIndex(successful, failures, entity);
        });

    stopWatch.stop();
    log.error(
        "Parallel reIndexing complete - in {} with {} successful and {} failed indexes of the Total: {}",
        stopWatch.formatTime(),
        successful.get(),
        failures.get(),
        mapping.allIndexedEntities().size()
    );
}

    /**
     * Zero-Downtime Implementation Method for MassIndexing Selected few Entities in the running instance
     *
     * @param types
     * @return void.
     */

    @Async
    @Override
    public void reindexAliasList(List<String> types) {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    SearchMapping mapping = Search.mapping(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());

    AtomicInteger successful = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger failures = new AtomicInteger();
    mapping
        .allIndexedEntities()
        .stream()
        .filter(sEntity -> types.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.equals(sEntity.jpaName())))
        .forEach(entity -> {
            processIndex(successful, failures, entity);
        });

    stopWatch.stop();
    log.error(
        "Parallel reIndexing complete - in {} with {} successful and {} failed indexes of the Total: {}",
        stopWatch.formatTime(),
        successful.get(),
        failures.get(),
        mapping.allIndexedEntities().size()
    );
}

    /**
     * Zero-Downtime Implementation Utility for MassIndexing in the running instance
     *
     * @param successful
     * @param failures
     * @param entity
     * @return void.
     */

    public void processIndex(AtomicInteger successful, AtomicInteger failures, SearchIndexedEntity<?> entity) {
    /**
     * Get the Alias names from the entity descriptor {@Link: ElasticsearchIndexDescriptor}
     */
    ElasticsearchIndexDescriptor descriptor = entity.indexManager().unwrap(ElasticsearchIndexManager.class).descriptor();
    String readName = descriptor.readName();
    String writeName = descriptor.writeName();

    try {
        /**
         * Get the Original index name from Elastic search client {@link: co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient}
         */
        Optional<String> iName = MapUtils
            .emptyIfNull(client.indices().getAlias(b -> b.name(writeName)).result())
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .findAny()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey());

        iName.ifPresent(origIndexName -> {
            try {
                String newIndexName = StringUtils.substringBefore(origIndexName, "-") + "-" + Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
                IndexState indexState = client.indices().get(g -> g.index(origIndexName)).get(origIndexName);

                /**
                 * Remove the alias association for write index to present index
                 */
                client
                    .indices()
                    .updateAliases(ub -> ub.actions(ab -> ab.remove(rb -> rb.index(origIndexName).alias(writeName))))
                    .acknowledged();

                /**
                 * Create new Index by copying all settings, mappings and aliases to new Index
                 */
                client
                    .indices()
                    .create(ci ->
                        ci
                            .index(newIndexName)
                            .mappings(m -> m.allField(indexState.mappings().allField()))
                            .mappings(indexState.mappings())
                            .settings(sb ->
                                sb
                                    .analysis(indexState.settings().index().analysis())
                                    .mapping(m ->
                                        m
                                            .totalFields(t -> t.limit(200000))
                                            .depth(t -> t.limit(20))
                                            .nestedFields(t -> t.limit(200000))
                                            .nestedObjects(t -> t.limit(20000))
                                    )
                            )
                            .aliases(indexState.aliases())
                    )
                    .index();

                log.debug("indexing for: {}", entity.javaClass());
                /**
                 * Initiate massIndexing
                 */
                MassIndexer massIndexer = searchSession.massIndexer(entity.javaClass());
                massIndexer
                    .monitor(monitor)
                    .batchSizeToLoadObjects(500)
                    .threadsToLoadObjects(2)
                    .typesToIndexInParallel(1)
                    .start()
                    .thenRun(() -> {
                        try {
                            /**
                             * 1. Remove the alias association for read index to present index
                             * 2. Delete the original Index
                             */
                            client
                                .indices()
                                .updateAliases(ub -> ub.actions(ab -> ab.remove(rb -> rb.index(origIndexName).alias(readName))))
                                .acknowledged();
                            client.indices().delete(d -> d.index(List.of(origIndexName))).acknowledged();
                            successful.addAndGet(1);
                            log.debug("Indexing successful for: {}", entity.javaClass().getName());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    })
                    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        failures.addAndGet(1);
                        try {
                            /**
                             * 1. Delete the new index
                             * 2. Create alias association back for write alias to the original Index
                             */
                            client.indices().delete(d -> d.index(List.of(newIndexName))).acknowledged();
                            client
                                .indices()
                                .updateAliases(ub -> ub.actions(ab -> ab.add(rb -> rb.index(origIndexName).alias(writeName))))
                                .acknowledged();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        log.error("Mass indexing failed!: {} {}", entity.javaClass().getName(), throwable);
                        return null;
                    });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Mass indexing attempt failed!: {} {}", entity.javaClass().getName(), e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Mass indexing attempt failed!: {} {}", entity.javaClass().getName(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you probably don't want to have a read alias set on the new index (`.aliases( indexState.aliases() )`) . Then on the first look having the massindexer where you have it seems fine, not sure what exception do you get, maybe add that ?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. it is working, but it is starting for all the entities in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will effectively reindex all your types in parallel, in the background, since `MassIndexer#start` does not block your thread. You're starting as many mass indexers in parallel as you have types, so yes this will lead to heavily parallel reindexing, regardless of of `typesToIndexInParallel()`.

If you want to index one type at a time, use `MassIndexer#startAndWait()`.

If you want to index `N` types at a time, in parallel, then split your code differently:

1. Create new indexes for all types
2. Execute the mass indexer on all types (`.massIndexer(Object.class)`) with `typesToIndexInParallel(N)`
3. Restore aliases for all types

Comment: added the `typesToIndexInParallel(N)` as shown in the pseudo code. But it is still starting all the entities.

Comment: As I said: "This will effectively reindex all your types in parallel, in the background, **since MassIndexer#start does not block your thread.**"